# Can someone explain the division in this proof of the sum of harmonic sequence? $(n+1)*h(n) - n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

So... this is the explanation my instructor gives in his PDF, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Use mathematical induction to prove that for all positive integers n:

H1 + H2 + . . . + Hn = (n + 1)Hn − n.

solution: The base case is easy. For the induction step we assume H1+H2+. . .+Hk = (k+1)Hk−k

for arbitrary positive integer k. Then

H1 + H2 + . . . + Hk+1 = (k + 1)Hk − k + Hk+1

= $\frac{(k + 1)*H_{k+1} − (k + 1)}{(k + 1) − k + H_{k+1}}$

= (k + 2)Hk+1 − (k + 1)

Why is there the division in the second step? I've been trying to solve this by doing:

$$(k+1)\frac{1}{k}-k + \frac{1}{k+1} == (k+2)\frac{1}{k+1} - (k+1)$$

but can't seem to make the two equal. So some explanation of his proof or some description of the faults in my methodology would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that:
$$
(k+1)(H_k)=(k+1)\left(H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=(k+1)H_{k+1}-\frac{k+1}{k+1}=(k+1)H_{k+1}-1.
$$
And so
$$
(k+1)H_k-k+H_{k+1}=(k+1)H_{k+1}-1-k+H_{k+1}=(k+2)H_{k+1}-(k+1).
$$

Comment: (k+1)(H_k) = {k+1}/k, but doesn't {1}/{k+1}-({1}/{k+1}) = 0? If so, this means a 0 = a non-zero?

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen Do you know what $H_k$ is? (Hint: it's not $\frac{1}{k}$.)

Comment: I guess I don't? I apologize if my question was stupid - but I do not have a mathematical background and this class *supposedly* only requires a basic grade 12 mathematics understanding.... which is obviously not true.

So.... I guess I'll go do some research and learn what this is. It strikes me that my prof was very unfair to spring this on us during a test when we may well have literally never seen it before :\

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen For $k\geq 1$, $H_k=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j}$. I believe this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: I think I get it now. Conceptually at least. I guess I just have to hope I don't see it on my test and from there I'll never see it again.